# Maximum Characters within a text box

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, multiline-text-field

I am trying to create a form which incorporates a text box which users can freely type their problems. However, I also wish to include a character limit to prevent novel-sized issues. The box needs to be multi-line/text wrapped and I wish the box to prevent further typing once character limit is reached. Or, failing that, include a character count which counts down.

I am aware that you can force the user to go to the next question once character limit is reached. However, as a user experience, I would prefer that the user is aware of what is happening.

Can anyone make suggestions?

Comment: check this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5986b95e-ff8e-4233-820d-882a814f2535/limit-infopath-textbox-to-256-characters?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious